# Column grid align how to fix it, im using

Tags: product-grid

Column grid align how to fix it, im using
im been trying to fig it out but nothing, im creating my own theme, im doing the change on xqep/xqeptheme/magento_catalog/web/css/souce/module/_listings.less also _module.less , im using magento/blank _listings.less file
here the picture if someone there can help me, 1 to 10 im a 4 or 5 in magento level so im new.[image]

Comment: This will help you to fix you : https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/category-view-images-not-aligned-rendered/td-p/427353

Answer (score 0):

You need to check 2 scenarios. it might be css or image resize related issue.

==> First is image resizes ratio related issue which you can solve using view.xml file in theme.

==> Second, you need to modify in theme less or css file for fixing this issue.

Comment: the images no the issue, they have been edited on PS 800px and also i edit view.xml to 200px for catalog. Where i see the issue is on the description. but i can't find it out what file to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Please add css in this file if you don't know which file is use **catalog/product/list.phtml**

**Note :** But this is not magento standard.

Answer (score 0):

**First Method** ->
The first way is to give min-height CSS for the product name so if the name is big, it will show the four-line height and if the name is short, then that will show the two or three lines and the remaining empty space so the price and add-to-cart button will be set as per the vertical.

**Second Method** ->
The second way is the line ellipse, which is used to show how many lines you can show the product name. See the below example to get a better idea.

```
.product-name {
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here, you can change the value of the `line-clamp` as per your requirement and you can set the column grid alignment.